# Group cohomology of Z/2Z

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $G=Z/2Z=\{1, g\}$. Consider the ring of integer $Z$ with the alternating action of G, i.e., $g\cdot n=-n$ for $n\in Z$ and an abelian group $M$ on which $G$ acts. It is well-known that the group cohomology $H^{n}(G, M)$ can be obtained by the free resolution 
$$\cdots Z[G]\to Z[G]\to Z[G]\to Z\to 0$$
of $Z$ with the trivial action, where the the maps are given by $1+g$, $1-g$. Is it true that the group $H^{n}(G, Z\otimes M)$ is isomorphic to $H ^{n+1}(G, M)$? Could you explain to me how to show it?